# How can I achieve component composition in AngularJS (similar to React render props pattern)?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, reactjs, components, angularjs-ng-transclude

I am trying to create a grid component in AngularJS that has it's grid items provided at runtime. (think render props pattern in React).

I am trying to build this using the "new" AngularJS components API along with transclusion.

```
<grid-items>
   <grid-item-type-1></grid-item-type-1>
</grid-items>


<grid-items>
   <grid-item-type-2></grid-item-type-2>
</grid-items>
```

Any of these should be valid. `<grid-items>` should take care of the data and the `<grod-item-type-x>` should take care of how each individual item is going to be dislpayed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After researching I have found out two ways to do this. One of them is to `require` the parent controller in the child component and use it's data, or by using the link function along with compile (this doesn't work using the components API), something like this:

```
link: function(scope, element) {
      scope.items.forEach((item) => {
        const tpl = "<" + item.type + " item=" + item + " ></grid-item>"
        const child = $compile(tpl)(item)
        element.append(child);
      });
    }
```

The above approach doesn't use transclusion but you can still use whatever child component is provided to the parent at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if I got it correctly there are some ways to do this. When defining your component, like this:

```
{
  restrict: 'E',
  bindings: {
    myProp: '@',
  },
  transclude: {
    'myTransclude': 'myTransclude',
  },
  template,
  controller,
  controllerAs: 'ctrl',
}
```

whatever you pass to `bindings` can be accessed from your component. So in the example above if you did something like this: `<my-component my-prop="hey" />` you can as well access `ctrl.myProp` an get your `hey` value.

In more complex ways you can use the transclusion item, that insides your myComponent template you'll have something like this:

```html
  <div ng-transclude="myTransclude"></div>
```

and everytime you'll use it'll be like this:

```html
<my-component>
    <my-transclude>
        <!-- whatever you wan to go inside your component  -->
    </my-transclude>
</my-component>
```

And, of course, you can have a HTML compile directive (I recommend searching for existing ones) where you could have your template and just use it

```html
    <div html-compile-directive="ctrl.myTemplate"></div>
```